# Django Rest Framework : Login

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, django-login

I'm trying to make a django rest API.
I've already created the registration API, now, I want to create the login API.
In my form, I'm sending two data : email and password.
I would like to check if there is an account that matched with these two fields.
I don't really know if what I am doing is the good way to do a login api.
Here is my code :
*views.py :*

```
...
#Log in
@api_view(['POST', ])
def log_in(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = {}
        email = request.POST.get['email']
        password = request.POST.get['password']
        password = hashlib.sha1(password, encode('utf-8'))
        account = memberArea.objects.filter(email = email, password = password)
        if account:
            data['succes'] = "Successfully connected"
            data['id'] = account.id
            data['email'] = accound.email
        else : 
            data['error'] = "email and password doesn't match !"
        return Response(data)
```

When I run my code, I get this error : `'method' object is not subscriptable`.
I think it's because `email` and `password` are not QuerySet.
If it's the method to login an user, how can I turn email and password into QuerySet ?
If there is another way which is commonly used to make login api, what is it?
Thanks by advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code:

```
#Log in
@api_view(['POST', ])
def log_in(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = {}
        email = request.POST.get['email']
        password = request.POST.get['password']
        password = hashlib.sha1(password, encode('utf-8'))
        account = memberArea.objects.filter(email = email).filter(password = password)
        if account:
            data['succes'] = "Successfully connected"
            data['id'] = account.id
            data['email'] = accound.email
        else : 
            data['error'] = "email and password doesn't match !"
        return Response(data)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the traceback?

Comment: Here is what I get : ```File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Documents\Flo\flo\api\views.py", line 106, in log_in
    email = request.POST.get['email'] TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable```

Comment: Can you print the value of request? Just add print(request) at 1st line of method.

Comment: I don't know how to print something with Django. Where can I see my results ?

Comment: you can see the result in terminal where you have started the server. Just use simple print function.

Comment: I only get that result : ```python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
July 02, 2020 - 15:34:35
Django version 3.0.6, using settings 'flo.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK. Method Not Allowed: /v1/login/
[02/Jul/2020 15:35:27] "GET /v1/login/ HTTP/1.1" 405 5720```

Comment: I got a 405 type error : ```HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed```

Comment: You are hitting the GET request to this endpoint. Please hit the post endpoint.

Comment: I don't really understand, I'm not already using a real form but only postman. Where can I see the post endpoint ?

Comment: You can see my updated post for hitting the post request rather that get?

Comment: Oh yes, that's what I get : ```TypeError at /v1/login/
'method' object is not subscriptable

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/v1/login/
Django Version: 3.0.6
Python Executable: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.3```

Comment: Are you able to get the value of request now?

Comment: I see that : ```Exception Type: TypeError at /v1/login/
Exception Value: 'method' object is not subscriptable
Request information:
USER: AnonymousUser

GET: No GET data

POST:
email = 'emailaddress@gmail.com'
password = 'azerty'

FILES: No FILES data

COOKIES: No cookie data```

Answer (score 0):

I just find the error.
I wrote `email = request.POST.get['email']` instead of `email = request.POST.get('email')`